# Expand button to cover full cell with colspan and rowspan

Tags: html, button, html-table, bootstrap-4

I need to insert a button inside a cell in a table. This button should fit entirely the cell.

```
<td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-block m-0" style="height:100%;">
       Button
   </button>
</td>
```

I tried the above code but the actual button it covers only the first row of the joined cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for?

The button row takes tha space of the below row as well

```
<table>
      <thead></thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>dolor sit amet</td>      
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block m-0" style="height:100%;">
            Button
           </button>
          </td>
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>dolor sit amet</td>      
          <td>test3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```